# Firebase Remote Config: How to Change Value Parameters

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am using Firebase Remote Config and want to change the value of a boolean parameter when I press on the button.

I tried this but it is not working:

```
 btntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           myconfiguration.getBoolean("btn_enable") = true;
        }
    });
```

and it gives me this error:

```
error: unexpected type
            myconfiguration.getBoolean("btn_enable") = state;
                                      ^
required: variable
  found:    value
```

Can someone help me setting the value of "btn_enable" to true?

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the values that are fetched from Firebase Remote Config in the client. The only ways to change those is through the Firebase console, or through the REST API/Admin SDKs, which are designed to only be used on a server.

But if you want to override a value from Remote Config in your app, you can just store the value that you get in a variable and then override *that* with your custom value.

So:

```
bool myValue = myconfiguration.getBoolean("btn_enable");
```

And then later:

```
myValue = state;
```

Comment: I was trying to develop an app that allows me to hide buttons in another app connected together on the same database on Firebase.  Is that mean that Remote-Config can not do this work?